# php find line number for a particular keyword

Tags: php

say I have a paragraph of text, with some new lines/line breaks. I would like to find the occurance of a certain keyword, and return the line numbers of those keywords. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about a website which got already rendered or are to talking about a portion of text which you would like to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/substr_count) in a manner like:

```
$line_number = substr_count($str, "\n", 0, strpos($str, 'keyword')) + 1;
```

where `$str` is the source string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string="
foo keyword bar
foobar
foobar
foo keyword bar
keyword
keyword";
var_dump(preg_grep('/keyword/',explode("\n",$string)));
?>
```

outputs:

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  string(15) "foo keyword bar"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "foo keyword bar"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "keyword"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "keyword"
}
```

So you could just do an `array_keys`  on that if you like.

Comment: A normal `grep` command from the command line usually way faster BTW, but of course less portable.